Docker Container for MariaDB, I am getting "bind: address already in use" error message
I am trying to setup a new Magento 2 local environment with Docker and the MariaDB container will not start and I get the following message.
"Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
Error: failed to start containers:"
I am new to programming so not sure how to clear this port or what is listening to this.  Any help would be appreciated.
I tried closing using lsof -nP -i:3306 to check and see that under IPv6 and IPv4, mariadbd is listening but not sure what to do from here.
